# C++ Template Copy Constructor for any data type

Tags: c++

Is it possible to write a copy constructor for a template for any data type?

For example

```
template <class T>
class DataObject {
   public:
      DataObject(T data, size_t size){
         this->data = data;
         this->size = size;
      }
      DataObject(const DataObject &dataobject){
          this->data = dataobject.data ;
          this->size = dataobject.size;
      }
      T data;
      size_t size;
};
```

The copy constructor above might work for some cases, but what about a `char[]`? Or other more complicated types of data. Is it possible to be worry free if someone makes

`DataObject<char*>`

`DataObject<std::string>`

`DataObject<SomeObject>`

Comment: "(...) possible to be worry free" - nope. What you can do is to write template specialization for some specific data types.

Comment: IMO, it's up to the client to make sure their class has correct copy semantics.  No different than any of the standard containers, for example `std::vector`.  If the user has a `std::vector<Whatever>`, and `Whatever` is not safely copyable, then that mistake is on the user, not `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely write a constructor template:

```
template<typename U>
DataObject(const DataObject<U>& dataobject) {
    // ...
}
```

The problem is knowing what to do in it. `dataobject.data` will not be the same type as `this->data`, so how do you initialize the latter? I you have well-defined conversions for every possible type, then go ahead.

By the way, this is not a copy constructor template. Just a constructor template.

Comment: Why is this `not a copy constructor` and also why do you prefer to use `typename` vs `class`? I've read the difference 100 times and still don't get it.

Comment: It's not a copy constructor because `DataObject<U>` is not the same type as `DataObject<T>`. I prefer `typename` here because it's not a class declaration. Mostly a matter of taste though.